# Como desabilitar um link de forma condicional com bind href no vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Eu tenho um projeto onde terá uma área populada dinamicamente com vue.js.

Mas os itens devem ser clicáveis ou não dependendo do nível de cada item.

Eu sei que no vue, da pra usar o **v-if**, mas tudo que tem dentro dessas tags desaparecem caso não corresponda. Eu gostaria de usar algo parecido mas eliminando o link clicável sem eliminar o que contém dentro da tag.

Por exemplo:

Eu tenho algo assim que deve aparecer quando os niveis dos itens seja acima de 2:

```
<a v-bind:href="['http://meusite.com.br/' + opts.cod]">
   <div>CONTEUDO AQUI</div>
</a>
```

E gostaria que ficasse assim, caso o nivel de item seja 1 ou abaixo:

```
   <div>CONTEUDO AQUI</div>
```

Ou se não der pra remover a tag de link, mas der pra anular da seguinte forma, também ajudaria:

```
<a href="#">
   <div>CONTEUDO AQUI</div>
</a>
```

Não sei se consegui explicar direito, espero que de pra entender.

Segue abaixo o código do que eu fiz até agora.

```js
    new Vue({
        el: '#v-for-lista',
        data: {
           itens: [{"cod":"xxxx1","nome":"Samanta Nivel 3","descricao":"Desc Teste 1","telprincipal":"","level":3},{"cod":"xxxxteste","nome":"Teste Nivel 1","descricao":"Este é nivel 1 e não deve ser clicável","telprincipal":"WhatsApp: (11) 99999-9999","level":1}, {"cod":"xteste2x","nome":"Teste Nivel 2","descricao":"Teste continuando","telprincipal":"","level":2}]
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="v-for-lista">    
    <div class="carditem" v-for="(opts, key) in itens">
     <a v-bind:href="['http://meusite.com.br/' + opts.cod]">
      <div class="card" v-bind:class="['level-' + opts.level]">
       <div class="header bg-level">
        <h2>{{ opts.nome }}</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ opts.descricao }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" v-if="opts.telprincipal">{{ opts.telprincipal }}</li>
       </div>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obrigada ♥

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar condições dentro do bind. Ex: **(condição ? if : else)**

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
<a v-bind:href="(opts.level >= 2 ? 'http://meusite.com.br/' + opts.cod : '#')">
```

Coloquei **>= 2** para ele buscar os itens que seja igual a 2 ou acima disto.

Desse modo você não exclui a tag `<a>` mas fica como no exemplo que você pediu.

Para tirar a tag de link, acho que o ideal seria criar um **componente** assim como o amigo **NoobSaibot** mostrou na resposta dele.

```js
    new Vue({
        el: '#v-for-lista',
        data: {
           itens: [{"cod":"xxxx1","nome":"Samanta Nivel 3","descricao":"Desc Teste 1","telprincipal":"","level":3},{"cod":"xxxxteste","nome":"Teste Nivel 1","descricao":"Este é nivel 1 e não deve ser clicável","telprincipal":"WhatsApp: (11) 99999-9999","level":1}, {"cod":"xteste2x","nome":"Teste Nivel 2","descricao":"Teste continuando","telprincipal":"","level":2}]
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="v-for-lista">    
    <div class="carditem" v-for="(opts, key) in itens">
     <a v-bind:href="(opts.level >= 2 ? 'http://meusite.com.br/' + opts.cod : '#')">
      <div class="card" v-bind:class="['level-' + opts.level]">
       <div class="header bg-level">
        <h2>{{ opts.nome }}</h2>
       </div>
       <div class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ opts.descricao }}</li>
        <li class="list-group-item" v-if="opts.telprincipal">{{ opts.telprincipal }}</li>
       </div>
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito Fernando VR, obrigada. Ficou mais simples de resolver assim. Não tira a tag de link, mas acaba sendo mais fácil de resolver. Obrigada por responder ♥

Comment: Tmj Samanta. Que bom que ajudei. Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um v-bind dinâmico, fiz [esse](https://codepen.io/mrdibre/pen/VExoEO) exemplo.

```
<div id="app">
  <a v-for="item in itens" v-text="item.nome"v-bind="formatBind(item.level)"></a>
</div>


 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: () => ({
   itens: [
  {
    "cod": "xxxx1",
    "nome": "Samanta Nivel 3",
    "descricao": "Desc Teste 1",
    "telprincipal": "",
    "level": 3
  },
  {
    "cod": "xxxxteste",
    "nome": "Teste Nivel 1",
    "descricao": "Este é nivel 1 e não deve ser clicável",
    "telprincipal": "WhatsApp: (11) 99999-9999",
    "level": 1
  },
  {
    "cod": "xteste2x",
    "nome": "Teste Nivel 2",
    "descricao": "Teste continuando",
    "telprincipal": "",
    "level": 2
  }
]
}),
methods: {
  formatBind(level){

    if(level === 1){
      return {}
    }

    return {
      href: 'stackoverflow.com'
    }

  }
}
})
```

Comment: Obrigada por responder, mas desse modo não serve para mim, pq o link também vai ser dinâmico. Mas obrigada mesmo assim ♥